# How do I install the database drivers?

Tags: 9

I'm trying to use Drupal 9 framework, and I'm stuck when setting up the database: I get the infamous error `Error: Class 'Drupal\pgsql\Driver\Database\pgsql\Connection' not found`.

When looking at the Drupal Core module `composer.json`, I see that the module expects a `drivers` directory to exist under `vendor/drupal`:

```json
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\": "lib/Drupal/Core",
            "Drupal\\Component\\": "lib/Drupal/Component",
            "Drupal\\Driver\\": "../drivers/lib/Drupal/Driver"
        },
```

Which seems to be confirmed by this issue:

https://www.drupal.org/node/3129492

Which clearly establishes that Database drivers are now provided by their own dedicated module.

The question is: where is this module and how can it be installed? I searched packagist for `drupal/drivers` but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is this an install-time or post-install issue?

Comment: I'm starting from scratch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not include the precise steps that occur which lead to the error message.

Answer (score 2):

> where is this module and how can it be installed?

It's not a single module containing all the drivers - each driver has its own module, already included with core.

For Postgres that's the `pgsql` module (for MySQL it's `mysql`). That's the module you need to enable, nothing else to download.

Comment: I found them inside the Drupal core module but they are not at all located where the core module autoloader expect them. This is very strange. I'll update my question.

Comment: You can ignore that last entry for the autoloader (`"Drupal\\Driver\\": "../drivers/lib/Drupal/Driver"`) - it's just an optional location that Drupal will look for contributed drivers in. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3123251

Comment: Reading again, it's not clear from the question what steps you've taken to get to where you're at - under normal conditions, the correct database module (with the driver) will be installed during the site install after you've selected the connection type. Are you doing anything non-typical for your install? Using a non-core profile? Installing via `drush site-install` with some exotic parameters? Anything like that?

Comment: I'm just requiring the core module, creating an entry point index.php that instanciates a custom kernel and that's it. I'm using the framework to create a custom CMS - as I always did up to Drupal 8 - instead of installing a pre-configured site with drush. The documentation of Drupal 9 is very lacking, even more so than Drupal 8 it seems, when it comes to build a CMS instead of configuring a pre built one.